# Getting 'E/launcher - Error: spawn EACCES' error while trying to run protractor tests in Unix machine

Tags: unix, jenkins, protractor

I am getting below mentioned error while running the protractor tests in headless mode in Unix machine.
Thinking it might be due to some permission issue, I gave execute permission to 'protractor' file in protractor/bin folder and to the protractor conf file, but no help.

```
[12:27:50] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:27:50] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[12:27:50] E/launcher - spawn EACCES
[12:27:50] E/launcher - Error: spawn EACCES
  at exports._errnpException (util.js:1024:11)
  at ChildProcess.spawn(internal/child_process.js:325:11)
  at Object.exports.spawn(child_process.js:493:9)
  at exec (/Ruser1/home/user1/Project1/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/exec.js:116:27
  at resolveCommandLineFlags.then.args (/Ruser1/home/user1/Project1/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:219:25)
  at <anonymous>
```

I tried running my tests from terminal as well as from jenkins using command:

```
./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor config/test1_cucumber.conf
```

But getting the same error. I have set `directConnect=true` in my conf file and passing `--headless` in chromeOptions.

Comment: pls post the complete error log here