# 'E/launcher - Error: spawn EACCES' error while trying to run protractor tests from Jenkins(Unix machine)

Tags: angular, jenkins, protractor

[Getting 'E/launcher - Error: spawn EACCES' error while trying to run protractor tests in Unix machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51772260/11012874) Did someone get a solution for this error?

My actual error [Error while downloading geckodriver during webdriver-manager update from jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59527871/error-while-downloading-geckodriver-during-webdriver-manager-update-from-jenkins/59532238#59532238)

As a workaround, i tried using selenium stand alone server + firefox(geckoDriver). 
With **directConnect=false** in configuration, i am getting the below error:

```
[13:41:20] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[13:41:20] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[13:41:21] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://xxx:4445/wd/hub
[13:41:21] E/launcher - Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'xxx', ip: 'xxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-754.23.1.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[13:41:21] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'xxx', ip: 'xxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-754.23.1.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/x/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/x/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/x/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/x/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/x/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index.js:521:41)
    at createDriver (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/x/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/x/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:632:16)
    at Local.getNewDriver (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/x/workspace/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:53:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/x/workspace/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/x/workspace/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/x/workspace/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/x/workspace/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/x/workspace/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
[13:41:21] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

When i use **directConnect=true**, i get the below error:

```
> ng e2e --configuration=dev --webdriverUpdate=false

Your global Angular CLI version (8.3.19) is greater than your local
version (8.3.12). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
[13:46:56] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[13:46:56] I/direct - Using FirefoxDriver directly...
[13:46:56] E/launcher - spawn /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/x/workspace/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.26.0 EACCES
[13:46:56] E/launcher - Error: spawn /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/x/workspace/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.26.0 EACCES
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
[13:46:56] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

Comment: pls post the complete error log here

Comment: 0


I am trying to run webdriver update from jenkins. I am downloading geckoDriver and chromeDriver. Chrome driver is downloading and unzipping properly. But gecko driver download is not working. However this is working fine from local. Issue occurs only in jenkins(Linux server) Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59527871/error-while-downloading-geckodriver-during-webdriver-manager-update-from-jenkins/59532238#59532238

Comment: @PujaBhattacharya I have updated my issue in the content. please check